# Lower bound for the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function implies it is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am working on the following problem from Stein and Shakarchi:

Let $f$ be an integral function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\|f\|_{L^1} = 1$ and let $f^*$ by the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function corresponding of $f$.

- Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $f$ is not identically zero, then $f^*(x) \geq c/|x|^d $ for some $c > 0$ and all $|x| > 1$.
- Conclude that $f^*$ is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
- Then, show that the weak type estimate $m(\{x:f^*(x) > \alpha \}) \geq c/\alpha$ for all $\alpha > 0$ whenever $\int|f| = 1$, is best possible in the following sense: if $f$ is supported in the unit ball with $\int|f| = 1$, then $m(\{x:f^*(x) > \alpha \}) \geq c'/\alpha$ for some $c' > 0$ and all sufficiently small $\alpha$.

[Hint: For the first part, use the fact that $\int_B|f| > 0$ for some ball $B$.]

I am not really sure where to begin with this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wlog, take $f$ nonnegative.  Since $f \neq 0$, find an $R > 0$ large enough so that $\int_{B(0;R)} f > 0$.  Fix any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and take $S$ large enough so that $B(0;R) \subset B(x;S)$ (say $S = R + |x|$).  So $f^*(x) \ge \frac{c}{S^d} \int_{B(x;s)} f \ge \frac{c}{(R+|x|)^d} \int_{B(0;R)} f$, where $c^{-1}$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  It should be easy to obtain the last part of the estimate from here.

Comment: This doesn't establish the inequality for all $|x|\ge 1$, just for all $|x|$ sufficiently large, so this answer is incomplete.

Comment: I don't see where an assumption is made on $|x|$, but it's also been like 5 years since I've thought about this answer.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's not true that the maximal function $f^*$ is greater than or equal to $c/|x|^d$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^d$. A simple example is to let $f$ be the indicator function of $[-1,1]$. This answer at best shows that the maximal function is greater than or equal to $c/|x|^d$ outside of some large ball, and at worst is just incomplete. You can actually prove it for all $|x|\ge 1$, not just $|x|\ge R$ for some large $R$.

Comment: @AOritz - I don't think that really answered what I'm asking or have provided a valuable comment.  You said the answer is incomplete because it assumes that $|x|$ is sufficiently large.  I don't see where that assumption has been used.  Can you elaborate and indicate specifically where this assumption is being implicitly used?

Comment: Maybe you can start by showing exactly how $f^*(x)\ge c/|x|^d$ for all $|x|\ge 1$ based on your answer.

Comment: To answer Alex's question, notice that $|x|/(|x|+R) > 1/(1+R)$ as $|x|>1$. Do I have to spell out the last bit?

Comment: Actually we can make more clear about the $(R+|x|)^d$, and we use Binomial theorem and $|x|\ge 1$ to decomposition it and we can estimate it